# Using ogr2ogr for converting tables from non-public schema to GeoJSON

Tags: postgresql, geojson, ogr2ogr

I've used ogr2ogr to convert tables in PostgreSQL database to GeoJSON which works fine for the public schema. The question is how can I set the schema to non-public to access my tables? I've already using ACTIVE_SCHEMA option as follow but it gives me not existing relation error.

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" out.json "PG:host=localhost dbname=test user=postgres ACTIVE_SCHEMA=line" -sql "select * from Road_a"
```

error:

```
ERROR 1: ERROR:  relation "road_a" does not exist
LINE 1: DECLARE executeSQLCursor CURSOR for select * from Road_a
```

Comment: Try "select * from line.Road_a" to force the schema line

Comment: Remember the table name is case sensitive. If the table is `Road_a`, it must be double quoted

Comment: I've used the double quote for table name and also added the line.Road_a without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the combination of Sociabilis and JGH hints the problem solved as follow:

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" out.json "PG:host=localhost dbname=test user=postgres password=x" -sql "select * from line."\Road_a\""
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the syntax of your connection string documented in https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pg.html. The options that are supported within the connection strings are there common PostgreSQL options https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/libpq-connect.html.

Because ACTIVE_SCHEMA is a GDAL open option try this:

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" out.json "PG:host=localhost dbname=test user=postgres" -oo  ACTIVE_SCHEMA=line -sql "select * from Road_a"
```

Comment: Using your command make the same error: relation "road_a" does not exist.